# C# Elastic Search retrieving data with NEST

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I'm pretty new to Elastic Search / NEST and need some help with how to be able to query/filter my data.

I am trying to retire data from Elastic Search using NEST. Even though I am getting the correct count of data it has not mapped to the model class correctly. Could someone help me to identify what makes went wrong this?

This is what I am getting on Elastic Search:

[image]

This is what am getting on NEST.
[image]

Code - function

```
public async Task<List<WebstoreOperationLogModel>> GetAllWebStoreLogs(int WebStoreId)
{
      var response = await elasticClient.SearchAsync<WebstoreLogModel>(s => s
                                    .Index("webstore-logs")
                                    .Query(q => q.Term("WebstoreId", 
                                     WebStoreId.ToString())));

    var logList = response.Documents.ToList();  

    return mapper.Map<List<WebstoreOperationLogModel>>(logList);
}
```

Model Class

```
public class WebstoreLogModel
{
    public Guid WebstoreLogId { get; set; }
    public int WebstoreId { get; set; }

    public string LogMessage { get; set; }
    public int LogType { get; set; }
    public bool IsExceptionOccurred { get; set; }

    public DateTime LogDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution with some research. It's solved by putting   ElasticProperty attributes on the Model class.

**Modified model class**

```
    [ElasticsearchType(RelationName = "webstore-logs")]
    public class WebstoreLogModel
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the webstore log identifier.
        /// </summary>
        [Text(Name = "WebJobLogId")]
        public Guid WebJobLogId { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the webstore identifier.
        /// </summary>
        [Number(DocValues = false, IgnoreMalformed = true, Coerce = true,Name = "WebstoreId")]
        public int WebstoreId { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the log message.
        /// </summary>
        [Text(Name = "LogMessage")]
        public string LogMessage { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the type of the log.
        /// </summary>
        [Number(DocValues = false, IgnoreMalformed = true, Coerce = true,Name = "LogType")]
        public int LogType { get; set; }
  }
}
```